# How to embed a gui in my terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gui, tmux

Like I want to show the firefox in my tmux terminal, without showing it outside the terminal. Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in a window manager, your `tmux` runs in a terminal and this terminal is a window and also Firefox. And it's possible to restrict the position/size of your Firefox window to the position/size of your `tmux`-terminal window.

If you've started `tmux` in e.g. tty1, you can't have a Firefox window.

Comment: Like you have said. I want to restrict the position in my tmux pane? how to do it?